# filter and compute the length of a dataframe in python which contains values in different columns

Tags: python

Need your warmly help~~!please~~

I have two DataFrames(df1 and df2) like below:

df1:

```
a    | b
---- | ----
a1   | b1
a2   | b2
a3   | b3
a4   | b4
```

df2:

```
c
----: 

a1+b1

a3+b3

a3+b4+b3+a4

a1+b2+b3+a4+b1

a4+b4

a4+b4+b1
```

I would like to filter and compute the length of df2 which contains values in both df1.a and df1.b, like below:

```
a  |b  |new_col 
---|---|---
a1 |b1 |2
a2 |b2 |0
a3 |b3 |3
a4 |b4 |3
```

for example: the number 2 represents

```
2 = len(df2[(df2.c.str.contains('a1')) & (df2.c.str.contains('b1'))])
```

the real situation is I have over 1 rows in both df1 and df2, can anyone help?

thanks very much!!

Comment: You should format your code in a block with Ctrl-K or indent by 4 spaces. Thanks

Comment: Thank you~ I will~

Comment: Are these pandas dataframes?

Comment: yes, use pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the answer:

[code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzY9w.png)

[result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdEqL.png)

the code is:

```
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'], 'b': ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4']})
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c': ['a1+b1', 'a3+b3', 'a3+b4+b3+a4', 'a1+b2+b3+a4+b1+a3', 'a4+b4', 'a4+b4+b1']})

    df1['and_col'] = df1['a'] + '.*' + df1['b'] + '|' + df1['b'] + '.*' + df1['a']

    df1['or_col'] = df1['a'] + '|' + df1['b']

    def count(x):
        return len(df2[df2.c.str.contains(x)])

    df1['and_count'] = df1['and_col'].map(count)

    df1['or_count'] = df1['or_col'].map(count)

    print df1
```